# Assign "in" membership to variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, operators

I am currently wondering if there is a way to assign the `in` membership operator and `or` logic operator to variables (python 2.7) and use it to create `if` statements.  I am looking to remove a nested for loop.  Currently I create a list of unknown values that I want to check if they are in an unknown string variable and would like it create a long `if` statement by joining all of the values with a membership operator the unknown string variable.

```py
#current method
lst = ['apple', 'banana', 'kite']

val = 'pineapple'
for l in lst:
   if l in val:
      print val

#would like to do something like creating string list with format variable inputs
str_format_list ['apple {0} {1} {2}', 'banana {0} {1} {2}', 'kite {0} {1} {2}']

str_format = " ".join (str_format_list)

if str_format.format(in, val, or):
   print 'yes'
```

This method does not work but was wondering if there is something I could try.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) builtin function:

> any(iterable)
>
> Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If
>   the iterable is empty, return False

```
lst = ['apple', 'banana', 'kite']
val = 'pineapple'

if any(word in val for word in lst):
    print('yes')

# yes
```